# How to hide div of ascx from the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to hide a `div` which written in a `ascx`. I am hiding it from code behind of `aspx page` where this `ascx` is registered.

div code;

```
<div class="form-group col" runat="server" id="CorpCol" visible="false">
```

code behind;

```
System.Web.UI.Control CorpCol = FindControlRecursive(this.Master, "CorpCol");
CorpCol.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you modify the user control, and expose that "div" as a public property of the user control.

Not only then does your code become rather simple, but you also find when you drop multiple instances of that user control on a page, then the hide/show of each "instance" of that div becomes nice clean and easy code.

So, say a user control to select a hotel, then a start, and end date.

And let’s have "div" in that user control that we want to hide (or show).

So, our simple user control markup is this:

```
<div style="float:left">

    <h3>Select Hotel</h3>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotel" runat="server" 
        Width="200px"
        DataValueField="ID"
        DataTextField="HotelName" 
        AutoPostBack="true" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:30px;height:100px">
    <h3>Select Start Date</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:30px">
    <h3>Select Start Date</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date">
    </asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div id="mydiv" runat="server" style="float:left;margin-left:30px">
    <h3>My div area</h3>
    <img src='<%= ResolveClientUrl(@"~/Content/Rhotel.jpg") %>' 
        width="40" height="40" />
</div>
```

And the code for the user control:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cboHotel.DataSource =
                General.MyRst("SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
            cboHotel.DataBind();
            cboHotel.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel");
        }
    }

    public HtmlGenericControl MyDiv
    {
        get { return mydiv; }
    }
```

Note how we just expose the "div" as a public property. And since it is an object, then no "setter" is required, only the above "get". And note the “id" and runat="server" tag for that div.

Ok, now our web page. Let’s drop in the user control 2 times, and then have 2 buttons. One to hide (or show) the first user control div. The 2nd button will hide/show the 2nd user control div.

So, this markup:

```
        <h3>First user control</h3>
        <uc1:USelectHotel runat="server" ID="USelectHotel" />

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <hr style="border:solid 2px" />

        <h3>Second user control</h3>
        <uc1:USelectHotel runat="server" ID="USelectHotel1" />

                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <hr style="border:solid 2px" />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdDiv1" runat="server" 
            Text="Hide show div 1" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="cmdDiv1_Click"  />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdDiv2" runat="server" 
            Text="Hide show div 2" CssClass="btn btn-info"
            style="margin-left:35px" OnClick="cmdDiv2_Click"
            />
```

And the code behind for the 2 buttons:

```
    protected void cmdDiv1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        USelectHotel.MyDiv.Visible = !USelectHotel.MyDiv.Visible;
    }

    protected void cmdDiv2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        USelectHotel1.MyDiv.Visible = !USelectHotel1.MyDiv.Visible;
    }
```

So note how we can in code behind set USelecthotel1.MyDiv.Visible = false in code.

The result of above looks like this:

[image]

Comment: how mydiv comes inside USelectHotel uc?

Comment: Take close look at markup for the ascx. That UC has a div called  "mydiv". That is the control we are to hide, and show. The example code not limied to a "div" but you could use a text box or whatever. The only important part here is? That ONCE WE expose that control with a public method, then we are free to get that control value, or hide or show that control, or do whatever we want. So that div was part of the UC. Could have been a text box - code would be much the same.  So, I placed that div called "mydiv" for this demo and answer. Probably better to have used picture of hotel for example

Comment: As a simple follow up? The question was how on a given web page can code behind for that web page get easy use of controls in the UC. The above answer shows how, and the fact of using a div or text box does not really matter here. In above, we also have the start date and end date. So, once again, one could expose the start date text box, and end date text box with above concepts. Now, code behind can easy get the start date, and end date, and no messy "find control" or anything else is required. The resulting code behind becomes clean and simple, and that includes when multiple UC's are used.

Comment: For this example, the question was how can code behind on a given web page get at, and enjoy the controls in the user control? Answer: do the above, and in that example the div was placed in the user control since the question was how to get at controls in the UC. So, it would make no sense for this demo to use a div or any other control that not inside of the UC.  So, the placement of the div in the UC was done since the question was how we can use and get at such controls in the aspx page and its code behind.

Comment: i have separately created usercontrols and register on the page where i need it , <%@ Register Src="~/Common/WorkRequestForms/WRGeneral.ascx" TagName="General" TagPrefix="WR" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Common/WorkRequestForms/WRClientException.ascx" TagName="ClientException" TagPrefix="WR" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Common/WorkRequestForms/WRCmsUser.ascx" TagName="CmsUser" TagPrefix="WR" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Common/WorkRequestForms/WRProgramMaintenance.ascx" TagName="PM" TagPrefix="WR" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Common/WorkRequestforms/WRCardOrderFileCtrl.ascx" TagName="CardOrder" TagPrefix="WR" %>

Comment: First it is downright abusive to post code in comments that no one can possibly read. Also what is the point and purpose of above code and why does it matter? You asked me why in my example I placed the div in the uc? Answer: because you asked how to use and access controls in the uc from code behind on the aspx page.  So then what is the point or purpose of posting the above code in comments? (Edit your question and post that code in the question so we can read that code and understand why you posting that markup in comments which is impossible to read

Answer (score 0):

you must chaning style in code behind:

```
System.Web.UI.Control CorpCol = FindControlRecursive(this.Master, "CorpCol");
CorpCol.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

But the easiest way is to use JavaScript.
You can add jQuery to project and put the following code at the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
$("#CorpCol").click(function(){
 var CorpCol =  document.getElementById("CorpCol").style;
 if(CorpCol.display == 'none'){
    CorpCol.display = 'block';
 }
 else{
    CorpCol.display = 'none';
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: It says for CorpCol.Style.Add("display", "none"); that Style doesn't contain a definition.

Comment: I suggest that instead of sending a request to the server, use Jquery to reduce the load on the server

Comment: i got some condition which i can put in code behind only....so need to do it from server side